# Remove characters before string?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a huge CSV with content like so:

```
9,4300~SEAFOREL (VZ-1000984)
10,050T~KEERLA SWER (VZ-1000985)
11,RI-10~Richmond No.10 33kV (VZ-1000983)
12,366.FC~HUNT (VZ-1001094)
```

I want to get the following:

```
9,VZ-1000984
10,VZ-1000985
11,VZ-1000983
12,VZ-1001094
```

I have been playing with regex within Notepad++ but cant to get the desired match, in fact not even close to mention here.  Any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

testing with another editor, but assuming that notepad++ use the same rules

regexp:

```
,[^\(]*\(([^\)]*)\)
```

replace:

```
,$1
```